# how to chnage values of object coming in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Im trying to chnage the object values in map loop on nested array

**Object Examples**

```
var data = [[{name: 'test', values: [{isSelected: true}] }]]



 var resertData = data.map(filterArray => {
    return filterArray.map(filter => {
        return filter.values.map(values => {
            return values.isSelected = false
        })
    })
})
```

**required output should be**

```
[[{name: 'test', values: [{isSelected: false}] }]]
```

**and Im getting with my code**

```
'[[[false]]]'
```

Please help me guys

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Well clearly returning just the changed fields overwrites existing ones. Return entire objects specifying values of fields you want to change, and use object destructuring to preserve existing ones. Try this:

```
    var resertData = data.map(filterArray => {
    return filterArray.map(filter => {
        return {
            ...filter,
            values : filter.values.map(values => {
                return {isSelected : false}
            })

        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful.. now I understand what I'm missing

Comment: @Kamal My pleasure, also do mark it as the accepted answer if you found it satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

To update the property value in the original object. You can use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Live Demo **:**

```js
var data = [[{name: 'test', values: [{isSelected: true}] }]];

data.forEach(filterArray => {
    filterArray.forEach(filter => {
        filter.values.forEach(values => {
            values.isSelected = false
        });
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

Or you can achieve this via more cleaner way **:**

```js
var data = [[{name: 'test', values: [{isSelected: true}] }]];

const [[dataObj]] = data;

dataObj.values.forEach(o => o.isSelected = false);

console.log(data);
```